# Kill a process from a test automation Groovy script in Katalon Studio

Tags: groovy, process, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to check if the AUT is opening a PDF viewer and I want to kill the process after test execution is finished. This is the relevant line of code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /im AcroRd32.exe /f")
```

The test passes, but the Acrobat Reader is still open.

I thought the problem was that the `cmd.exe` isn't authorized to kill the process form Katalon Studio so I've set it to always run as admin, as described [here](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/).

If I run the

```
taskkill /im AcroRd32.exe /f
```

directly from the command line, Acrobat Reader shuts down as expected, but it still remains open if run from the Katalon script.

How can I kill it?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` just starts the process and returns Process object. and if you are not reading stdout & stderr the process could just stuck. use [Process.waitForProcessOutput()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput(java.lang.Appendable,%20java.lang.Appendable)) method to collect a result of execution and analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help You, remember that arguments should be putetd in "" , "".

```
String[] arguments = {
    // Arguments for program
}
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(arguments);
pb.inheritIO();

Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
pb.destroy();
```